# Why doesn't android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" adjust the screen when soft keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I can't seem to make the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" option work.
When the soft keyboard shows, the scroll view doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom part.

**Edit**: I tried using adjustPan instead (stateVisible|adjustPan) but what happens is the scroll view gets disabled.

**Solution**: Finally, I found a suggestion that works. I created an OnGlobalLayoutListener() and added it to my scroll view. I checked if the height of the root view of my activity(which is my scroll view) changed. If yes, I'm assuming that the soft keyboard is shown.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/2546729) for more info.

Here's my source code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        ...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            ...
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
</application>
```

Login Screen with keyboard - scroll view does not scroll
[image]

Desired result
[image]

Comment: Use  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Comment: Similar to adjustPan|stateVisible, this disables the scroll view.

Comment: Regarding your solution, I'd like to hear how you solved it knowing the keyboard is visible. Although this worked for me
``` loginScrollView.post(() -> loginScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN));```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**: Finally, I found a suggestion that works. I created an OnGlobalLayoutListener() and added it to my scroll view. I checked if the height of the root view of my activity(which is my scroll view) changed. If yes, I'm assuming that the soft keyboard is shown.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/2546729) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that I already tried that. What happens is the scroll view does not scroll anymore if adjustPan is used.

Comment: how I do that in xcode ? there'is an option to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You could automatically scroll to the bottom of your activity by yourself, by overriding the [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) callback in you `Activity` :

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});
```

This means you also have to tell your activity you want the callback to be called when the activity changes its layout by using the [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) attribute in the activity declaration in your **AndroidManifest** file :

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="screenLayout|screenSize" <!-- Don't know which could actually do the trick -->
    ... >
</activity>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: I added onConfigurationChanged() but it doesn't get called. Even after adding the configChanges parameter in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: How do you know it isn't called ? Did you try to simply print a message in the logcat to see ?

Comment: Hi. Yes. I added a Log.i() call inside the method. Anyway, I finally found a solution that works. I'll edit my post to include it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"
```

In layout xml bottom of all child layout of scrollview set one textview, such as

```
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/driverLoginScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:scrollbars="none">
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        .
        .
        .
       <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:textIsSelectable="false" />
       </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

I found that if I had set layout parameters on my scroll view, then it would not work. As soon as a removed the layout parameters it worked as expected. I can't explain why, just letting others know what worked for me.