# Android Scrollview gets overlapped by a view and keyboard

Tags: java, android, keyboard, overlap

I have searched the web for about 2 hours and no solution, now I will try it here.

My problem is that when I open the keyboard the scrollview gets overlapped by a view and the keyboard. I want to see the bottom elements of the scrollview.

Here are the screenshots: [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK9IR.png), [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zBER.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The scrollview doesn't respond to `adjustReize` like other views do, the solution (like other people have done e.g. [Why doesn't android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" adjust the screen when soft keyboard is shown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141168/why-doesnt-androidwindowsoftinputmode-statevisibleadjustresize-adjust-the-s)) will simply listen to the view's hierarchy and scroll to the bottom when the keyboard is shown